# QRCODE image to display on the android phone screen

Tags: android, qr-code

I want to generate a QR code for a string. In the cases I find in the forum, The generated QR is generating an image. I want the QR code to display on the screen with out having to save a copy of it.

Comment: Why? Is it so much effort to save a copy of it in temporary storage?

Comment: Is it possible to create an image at runtime?? I am new to QR code.Would be a great help if u could guide me on how to do this. I have created a bitmap using the zxing. I want to know if this could be used to display the generated QR.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible to generate a QR code image at runtime. For instance, the website "Wolfram Alpha" does it. Try this URL:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=qr+code+www.stackexchange.com

So if you can call that website and capture its output, then you can display the QR code in your app.

Another potential source could be http://zxing.appspot.com/generator/.

Comment: Thankx Roy. My requirment is that the android app which i am going to design should generate a QR code from a String object and make is appear on the screen. I would relly appreciate if you could help me understand how exactly i can proceed with the coding.

Answer (score 0):

The zxing project has code to [encode QR codes](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk#trunk/core/src/com/google/zxing/qrcode/encoder). You can use and embed this code, as long as you follow the Apache License. Barcode Scanner displays QR codes on screen; you can look at its source in the same project to see how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the easiest way to generate QR code is to use Google Charts API. Here is page with relevant documentation - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/infographics/docs/qr_codes.html

Here is quick example of QR code for "Hello world", 150x150 pixels:
https://chart.googleapis.com/chartchs=150x150&cht=qr&chl=Hello%20world&choe=UTF-8

It works the best if it is used in web app (inside browser). Otherwise you have to load the image over the web connection.